# Rageshaper and Enlarge person

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, creature-size

In Paizo's latest supplement release, [*Ultimate Wilderness*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9ujo/discuss?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Wilderness), we see an Archetype for a class also announced in that book; the *Rageshaper* variant of the *Shifter*.

The *Rageshaper* has the following class feature:

> **Devastating Form (Su):**
>   A rageshaper can enter a state of intense fury, transforming into a living engine of destruction. This ability functions as the barbarian’s rage class feature, except entering this state of fury requires a full-round action that provokes attacks of opportunity and has additional effects as noted below.
>   *At the start of the rageshaper’s next turn, he not only gains the benefit of rage but also grows one size category larger* (though worn equipment and held items do not increase in size). Armor or clothing the rageshaper wears that doesn’t accommodate his changing size immediately gains the broken
>   condition.
>   [... text about the rest of the ability, not concerning size increases...]
>   *At 10th level, the rageshaper can grow up to a maximum of
>   two size categories larger* with devastating form and his rage
>   is now treated as greater rage.
>   *At 20th level, the rageshaper can grow up to a maximum
>   of three size categories larger* with devastating form and his
>   rage is treated as mighty rage.

My question is: *Would this size increase, as written, stack with that from effects such as Enlarge Person, or Expansion?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t5u):

> Size increases and effective size increases: How does damage work if I have various effects that change my actual size, my effective size, and my damage dice?
>
> As per the rules on size changes, size changes do not stack, so if you have multiple size changing effects (for instance an effect that increases your size by one step and another that increases your size by two steps), only the largest applies. The same is true of effective size increases (which includes “deal damage as if they were one size category larger than they actually are,” “your damage die type increases by one step,” and similar language). They don’t stack with each other, just take the biggest one. However, you can have one of each and they do work together (for example, enlarge person increasing your actual size to Large and a bashing shield increasing your shield’s effective size by two steps, for a total of 2d6 damage).

So this size increase wouldn't stack with either *enlarge person* nor *expansion*.